# Javascript use variable inside match regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a simple regular expression inside a match function like this:

```
text.match(/.{1,20}/g);
```

Is it possible to replace the `20` with a dynamic variable?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `RegExp` constructor, not the literal. That allows you to do string concatenation or interpolation as you please:

```js
let n = 20;
let r = new RegExp(".{1," + n + "}", "g");

text.match(r);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
> n = 3; text = 'abcd'; text.match(new RegExp(`.{1,${n}}`, 'g'));
[ 'abc', 'd' ]
>
```